# Remove item from Luminus Database in Clojure

Tags: database, clojure, luminus

I am currently writing a website via **Clojure** code that runs on a **Luminus** based framework. I have a database that stores **name** and **to-do tasks**. The **HTML** code behind the route that has the text fields for inputting names and to-do tasks first outputs:

1. The time that the task was published.
2. The task that was inputted
3. The name of the person who inputted the task.

Just below this, I have the two text fields, as expected, and a button that submits the task to the page, and refreshes the page.

Each task is stored in the database as it is submitted, by calling **SQL** function that I have written.

I would *like* to have a button of some sort next to each item in the list that calls a SQL function on the particular item of choice, and removes it from the database (and thus, removes it as a task to do) -- i.e a **"COMPLETED"** button.

I know how I could have a link next to each item, simply by modifying the HTML code, but how would I make the link call a SQL function and then remove the item?

Is this possible to do? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** *SOLVED*

I figured this out. I simply created links that re-routed to another page based on the message parameter. That new page called a SQL function with the message parameter that was passed to it in which the SQL function deleted the item from the table.

Comment: If you solved it, edit the solution out of your question and publish it as an answer instead. You'll be able to "accept" it within a day.